# How to find Difference in two Collections<T> in C#

Tags: linq, collections

I have two collections of following class

```
public class ABC
{
   public int studentId {get;set;}
   public int schoolId {get;set;}
   // Class has other properties too both above two are the keys

}
```

Now i have two collections of ABC

```
  ICollection<ABC> C1 = {Some Data}
  ICollection<ABC> C2 = {Some Data}
```

I want to find objects of ABC in C1 that are not in C2 based on keys i-e StudentId and SchoolId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var diff = C1.Except(C2)
```

Please also note, that in order to track equality you can override Equals method, or implement and pass IEqualityComparer to Except method

```
class ABCEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ABC>
{
    public bool Equals(ABC b1, ABC b2)
    {
         return (b1.studentId == b2.studentId) && (b1.schoolId == b2.schoolId)
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ABC b)
    {
        return 7*b.studentId.GetHashCode() + b.schoolId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Than you can use

```
var diff = C1.Except(C2, new ABCEqualityComparer())
```

Comment: Need to check based on key fields only

Comment: You can do that by overloading equals too. Just for the record https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I said about Equals in answer @Brduca, also I think it make sense to override Equal to return full equality, but this case we need only some fields equality...

Comment: Do i need to implement GetHashCode as well

Comment: In case of IEqualityComparer, you  have to, just return 7*b.studentId.GetHashCode() + b.schoolId.GetHashCode()... editted

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan, I got it (and made a +1 on your answer), they are pretty much the same. But in C# you can overload other operators then Equal, so will never know when will need it...